# Finding force distribution using accelerometer data

Tags: automotive-engineering, measurements, sensors, signal-processing, frequency-response

The team I'm currently working for is trying to compare bushings with different durometer ratings in the front suspension using single axis(z) accelerometer data during curb impacts. The current problem at hand is that the amplitude recorded is close to one g or two and noisy at curb impacts. I did a FFT and PSD analysis to check that none of the contributing frequencies match the resonance frequency of the accelerometer. This was followed by Inverse FFT of that signal.

Now my team thinks of forming some kind of force distribution using the denoised data.

Is it a good experiment using accelerometer data to compare the two different durometer bushings? For some reason, I think there is a better way to compare the ride quality using the different bushings.

The two accelerometers are attached below the seat and on the link connecting bushing to the base.

Comment: In principle, it is a good application for an accelerometer. Where the accelerometer is mounted may make a big difference, and of course you would want to make sure the signal path is designed well.

Comment: Make sure you handle the accelerometer based on what it is- charge output ones are best used with a charge amp which will smooth it for you (sometimes as a "velocity") while strain gage types output current.  How sure are you that Z is and stays parallel to gravity as you hit the bump? Triax plus gyro may be necessary for anything beyond a relative comparison such as "force"